# How to design this horizantal scrollview?

Tags: android

[image]

How to create a `HorizantalScrollview` for this, but when I keep button in `HorizantalScrollview` button `width` changes to `wrap_contant`I want it to be `match_parent` only and when I swipe the button I need to get the `RecyclerView` for `RecyclerView` I can manage by keeping the `LinearLayout.Horizantal` in code. All want is button to be `Match_Parent` and when I swipe I need to get `recyclerview`

Comment: Why use `HorizantalScrollview` just use `RecyclerView` only . You can inflate different layouts depending on position .

Comment: Look at this examples https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

While the setup you've shown in the illustration should be doable, it is not considered a good practice. `RecyclerView` brings efficiency to a scrollable element and putting `RecyclerView` in another scrollable element (e.g. the `HorizontalScrollView` in your example) can make the efficiency benefits go away and can make it less UX-friendly.

What you should do is to create a `RecyclerView` that can handle multiple view types in the `Adapter`. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46454246/1993204) should be enough for you to understand the concept.

And your case should look more like this:

[image: recycler]

(*the illustration is for explaining purposes only, it's not entirely accurate as the `RecyclerView` should **not** wrap its content*)

Answer (score 0):

Use HorizontalScrollView it's very simple like normal scrollview

See below example

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null" \\remove it if you don't want to use
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null" \\optional
            android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@null" \\optional
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

\\define your list of item here that you want to scroll


 </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```